# Histogram with skewed data

Tags: statistics

I have a set of data which I want to plot a histogram of to get a feel for which bins contain the most items. There are 200,000 data points which range from 0.08 to 5,000.

Problem is I know the data is heavily skewed towards the lower end. I don't want to lose resolution at that lower end because it's quite important. Hence equal bin sizes aren't appropriate, and 4,000 bins is too cumbersome.

Is it *generally acceptable* to have changing bin sizes as we go up the range? Are there any alternative methods I might look at instead?

Comment: I think it is perfectly acceptable --- just remember to make the areas of the rectangles proportional to the number of elements in the bin.

Comment: Do you have access to software to make the histograms. Some software will accept unequal bin widths and use appropriate areas for each bar. The vertical scale is then called 'Density' rather than 'Frequency', or 'Relative frequency'. BTW: I think maybe you mean your data are skewed toward the _upper_ end. The direction of the_skew_ is in the direction of the long tail, not the direction of the greatest concentration.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'm just doing this somewhat manually in Excel. I'm more concerned that if I vary the bin width, then visually, on first perceptions it appears as though some areas are more dense than they really are, simply because it contains more points. Thinking I might just split this particular data into two groups and deal with it that way.